# Pyspark .pipe() would hang indefinitely on non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, apache-spark, encoding, pyspark

Simple example, I've been able to reproduce with Spark 1.6.2 and 2.1.1 (Python 2.7.9 under Jupyter):

```python
sc.parallelize(['a']).pipe("cat").collect()
```

yields `[u'a']`, but try

```
sc.parallelize(['å']).pipe("cat").collect()
```

*and it never returns*

Tried representing strings with `unicode`, no luck.

This must be something widely known that I'm missing.

Comment: Personally I would just switch to Python 3, but in general, this is a bug in PySpark.